# Recovering files with recovery key after double FileVault activation - is that possible?

Tags: disk-encryption, forensics, macos, filevault

Let's imagine I have a work macbook with ssd and I use FileVault, and the company has the FileVault recovery key. I want to make sure my data is erased and unrecoverable, what is the best way to proceed?

I can do a full reinstall of the operating system, which in turn would re-enable FileVault changing the previous recovery key (again, known to the company as well). This would mean that the full disk encryption is done again over the previous disk encryption.

Would the company still be able to recovery the original deleted files in this case by knowing both recovery keys?